# Unable to get the values of an element using selenium java

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium webdriver with Java and Maven project. In a webpage there are few fields and I want to get the value of one the fields. These values which are shown were entered in the previous screens and still not stored in the database.

I am unable to get the value of an webelement.

I tried using `gettext()`, `getAttribute()` and `(String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].value", element)`. But they either return blank or null as values.

When I tried to use locators xpath or ID, i got error that "could not locate the element". So i used CSS locators.

I am expecting to retrieve those values and store in a variable for further use.

```
<div class="row g-3 mb-3" xpath="1">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap" data-name="nombre">
      <input type="text" name="nombre" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required form-control" id="nombre" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Nombre*" data-gtm-form-interact-field-id="0">
    </span>
  </div>
```

Comment: Update the question with the text based HTML of the element.

Comment: <div class="row g-3 mb-3" xpath="1">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap" data-name="nombre"><input type="text" name="nombre" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required form-control" id="nombre" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Nombre*" data-gtm-form-interact-field-id="0">
 </span>
  </div>

Comment: Share the WebElement syntax used to identify the element. Since you are getting could not locate the element error, the issue would be with xpath/css locators used to identify the webelement.

Comment: Try `List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.YOUR LOCATOR HERE);` to see how many elements you get. If more than one, you need more precise locator or use on top `WebElement element = elements.get(i);`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all for your help. Finally it worked. I used the below command:

String data_nombre = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.getElementById('nombre').value");